# Printing to Impact Printer from Command Line

Tags: raspbian, printing, lp

I have a Raspberry Pi running Raspbian and I bought an impact printer (Epson LX-350) that I plan on hooking up to the computer via USB cable once it arrives. My goal is to be able to have a script periodically output lines of ASCII text to the printer as certain events happen. I don't care about it being pretty, in fancy fonts, large font sizes, worrying about files, or worrying about spooling print jobs from multiple users over multiple printers.

It seems like I can plug in the printer, not install any specific drivers, and then use commands like `echo "Line 1\r\nLine 2\r\nLine 3\r\n" | lp -d /dev/usb/lpXXX`.

I don't have the printer right now to try it out on, but am I missing anything I should research while I'm waiting for the printer to arrive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know whether cups (which is probably behind your `lp` command) supports that printer at all – or whether it's wise to use it; it's not like you want to print complete pages of anything. There might be an `lp` program
you need if the printer emulates a *parallel* port, never dealt with that.

Luckily, printers like yours have rather simplistic command languages – ESC/P in your case. You'd want to read the [reference manual](https://epson.ru/upload/iblock/057/esc-p.pdf), especially the example in section R-1.

You'll probably just prepare a "printer setup command sequence" in a file (say "setup"), pipe that file into your printer port (`cat setup > /dev/ttyUSB0` or so), and then you'd just pipe lines of text into the same device file.

Comment: Thank you very much! That was a very interesting read and I'm excited to try it out once the printer arrives. I noticed on page 17 of the PDF that the LX-350 isn't listed at all. How did you get it being in the ESC/P column? I was thinking it would be in the 9-Pin ESC/P column but it's not even listed there.

Comment: from the product page itself. Note that the document is from 2004 and *can't* know about more modern printers